# HttpServerUtility.Transfer vs Server.Transfer?

Tags: asp.net, server.transfer, httpserverutility

What's the difference between [HttpServerUtility.Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.transfer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [Server.Transer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are the same. The name of the class that has the `Transfer` method is `HttpServerUtility`, but an instance of the `HttpServerUtility` is available from several objects through the `Server` property.

For example, the `Page` class has a `Server` property, so while you are inside methods for a web page, you can use `Server.Transfer` to call the method.

Answer (score 2):

`Server.Transfer` is a VBScript method in ASP Classic.

`HttpServerUtility.Transfer` is an ASP.Net method that does the same thing.